# Is it possible to use a left outer join sql statement if column names are different in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, join

I am working in VB.net 2013, windows form applications, and I need to do a left sided join sql statement, first time I have ever tried it. My question is, can you cross-reference two tables if the columns names are different but the data they have is the same. In my example I have tableA and tableB. TableA has a column named "JobNum" and TableB has the column named "JobNumber." Considering this is it still possible to do the join statement. Here is my code:

```
 'load Job List
    Try
        'set/open sql connection
        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
            conn1.Open()
            'Using comm1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select JobNum, Shear from Production.dbo.[Floor Cell Jobs\Shears]", conn1)
            Using comm1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT JobNum FROM Production.dbo.[Floor Cells Jobs\Shears] LEFT OUTER JOIN Production.dbo.tblFCOrdered ON Production.dbo.[Floor Cells Jobs\Shears].JobNum = Production.dbo.fcOrdered.JobNumber", conn1)
                'dim the variable rs as an sql datareader and execute that reader with sql comm1
                Dim rs As SqlDataReader = comm1.ExecuteReader
                'dim dt as a new datatable and load it into data set rs
                Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
                dt.Load(rs)

                'set the combobox vale and display members
                CBJob1.ValueMember = "JobNum"
                CBJob1.DisplayMember = "JobNum"

                'set the datasource for combobox CBJob1
                CBJob1.DataSource = dt
            End Using
        End Using
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure thing, you just do something like this

```
SELECT
  *
FROM Table1 A
left join Table2 B on (A.JobNum = B.JobNumber)
```

Comment: You can give your tables a 'nickname' by assigning some value after your table name. In my case Table1 is now also known as A. This makes it a whole lot easier to reference the correct tables and keeps it simple :-)

Comment: I changed it over to your code and the code is running but the job numbers in tableB are still being shown in the drop down box that is bound to Table A. I want the combobox I am binding TableA with to NOT show the jobs in Table B. Should i be using a different sql join statement other than left join?

Comment: "SELECT * FROM Production.dbo.[Floor Cell Jobs\Shears] A left join Production.dbo.tblFCOrdered B on (A.JobNum = B.JobNumber)

Comment: @Cheddar The way I am reading your select-query you will still only see the results from table A, as you are not selecting anything from table B. Just by joining to tables to the left will not give you any more new data unless you select it in the select-query :-)

Comment: ^^ I am not expecting too see any kind of new data. I need any Job Numbers in TableB to be removed from the TableA selection. If i dont, an end user could select a job number that has already been selected and receive a primary key error.

Comment: I see, then using a join is not the right approach. Joining to tables is to get a combination of the two. So you are trying to get all the numbers from TableA that are NOT in TableB?
`SELECT JobNum FROM TableA WHERE JobNum not in (SELECT JobNumber FROM TableB)`

Comment: You don't even need brackets, it works without them too.

Comment: Good practice thou ;-)

Comment: No worries. Good luck with the project :-)